# High classification metric results

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, multiclass-classification

I am attempting crop type identification using machine learning. This is a pixel wise classification. I have 16 classes (targets) and this is the shape of my training and testing datasets:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test=train_test_split(Features, Labels, test_size=0.25)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_test.shape
#((48330, 420), (16110, 420), (48330,), (16110,))
```

I wanted to first experiment with a baseline model, so I did the following:

```
classifier=RandomForestClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(Y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(Y_test,y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(Y_test, y_pred))
```

And this is the final result:
[image: img]

I am not sure what happened here, why do I have such high metrics?
PS: My dataset is highly unbalanced.

Answer (score 1):

your dataset is unbalanced. try to fixed it firstly then use hyperparameter tuning.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into your training and test data, most likely your data is not arranged in the way you want.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please ?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no overlapping between your training and test datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start from less number of trees in the classifier and set max_depth to 2 or 3? That should a good starting point. If it still does the same thing then simplify the model even further.